# Cisco Anyconnect: does it support Start Before Login (SBL) on Vista?

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa

We have a Cisco ASA 5505 running version 7.2.  The current config includes both a site-to-site VPN (ipsec-l2l) and a remote access VPN where users connect using the Cisco VPN client 5.0.06 (ipsec-ra).

Because the cisco VPN client lacks support for Windows 7, 64 bit OSes and SBL on Vista we need to upgrade to the AnyConnect client, which means the ASA needs to be upgraded to version 8.X.

I have two questions about this upgrade (being asked separately)

2) Does Anyconnect support Start Before Login on Windows Vista 32bit?  There is conflicting information on the Cisco site:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect20/administrative/guide/admin1.html#wp1008856

The Windows Vista version of AnyConnect (32- and 64-bit) supports everything that the Windows 2000 and Windows XP versions support, **with the exception of Start Before Logon**.

http://www.cisco.biz/en/US/products/ps6120/products_configuration_example09186a00809f0d75.shtml

Differences Between Windows-Vista and Pre-Vista Start Before Logon

The procedures to enable SBL differ slightly on Windows Vista systems. Pre-Vista systems use a component called virtual private network graphical identification and authentication (VPNGINA) to implement SBL. **Vista systems use a component called PLAP to implement SBL.**

In the AnyConnect client, the Windows Vista Start Before Logon feature is known as the Pre-Login Access Provider (PLAP) [...] **The PLAP function supports Windows Vista x86 and x64 versions.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this with Win7, Both 32 and 64-bit.  I would imagine it is the same with Vista as they use the same PLAP component.

Start before login works, but is more annoying to use (IMO) than the implementation in the CVPN client.  In essence, you need to download the PLAP component separately from cisco's website, and then in order to use it you must select 'Switch User' , then the unlabeled 'network connect' button every time you want to use it.